# Hosting Spring Boot microservice (REST API) - What are my options?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, deployment

I have some experience developing microservice using spring boot applications but I'm a beginner when it comes to hosting and deploying those applications.

Below some characteristics of my microservice:

- Is a spring boot (tomcat) application (latest version)
- The database used to store data it is MySql (latest version)
- The source code is on github as VCS
- Continue integration tool: TBD
- I need at least 2 environments (development and production)
- The application currently its address around 3K end-users by year, so the traffic is NOT, unfortunately, a big issue :(
- The budget I intend to allocate is up to 200$ by year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could take a shot at hosting it on Microsoft Azure.

Currently [they have support for Tomcat](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/tomcat-for-azure-app-service-on-linux/) and you could try to deploy the app in seconds with their App Services, which can easily be hooked up to a Github repo for continuous deployment. However, you will almost certainly need to dig into the config to make a successful build.

I also think this could be a fitting solution for you, since they offer you the opportunity to [try it for free for 12 months](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/), with $200 credit. This appears to fit what you would need for your first year.

If you can make it work under Azure's constraints for the first year, you can evaluate whether you'd like to renew or choose a different provider!

Best of luck to you.

Comment: What about using **pivotal cloud foundry**?

Comment: Sounds like it could be worth a shot! I honestly haven't tried it though, so I can't argue for or against using it based on experience.